# Jetty ProxyServlet does not redirect the request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty

I want to redirect the request to another server which handles the request and does business logic. I tried with ProxyServlet but it does not work.

Here is my implementation of main server which gets all requests:runs on localhost:8081

```
    Server server = new Server(8081);

    // 2. Creaing the WebAppContext for the created content
    WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext();
    ctx.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
    ctx.setContextPath("/jetty-jsp-example");

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = ctx.addServlet(ProxyServlet.class,"/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("maxThreads", "1");
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("proxyTo", "localhost:8080");

    ctx.setAttribute("o:Prg.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$");

    org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
    classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
    server.setHandler(ctx);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

I want to forward this request a server running on port 8080. My target service url path is: localhost:8080/jetty-jsp-example/sv/endpoint .

I have imported jetty proxy as following

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-proxy</artifactId>
<version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
```

Moreover, I read that our custom proxy servlet should be required to extend the proxyservlet class and override the rewriteURL() method.But when I tried that it gave me compile error.
Anyone let me how can I solve this please. I use jetty 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, I was wondering how to get this working the other day too. I had to use the subtype `BalancerServlet` with the following init parameters:

```
// give your servlet a name
jerseyServlet.setName("proxy");
// parameter is 'balancerMember.NAME.proxyTo'
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("balancerMember.proxy.proxyTo", "http://yourdownstreamserver.com/");
```

Docs around configuration are a bit sparse; I ended up having to look at the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/BalancerServlet.java). Also note that Jetty proxy doesn't support proxying to downstream services over SSL.

Comment: @Débora that's correct, sorry I omitted that part! Maybe I haven't dug into the code enough but I'm not sure why the base `ProxyServlet` isn't abstract, it doesn't seem to do much on its own...

Comment: @Débora I'm pretty sure I imported the exact same version of `jetty-proxy` to my project; did you import it? I'm not sure how it works at runtime if the class wasn't found.

Comment: @Débora yup, that sounds good, think that's the latest stable and I'm using that too. I have the `jetty-server`, `jetty-servlet` and `jetty-proxy` dependencies in my POM and I'm using `ServletContextHandler` to add servlets. Have a look at the documentation around embedding jetty with servlets